# Windows Microsoft Excel : How to average over the columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, average

I know there are already a few questions about averaging in excel on the SE, but I looked at them and didn't really understand what to do (I'm just starting using excel)...

I have a file with columns of numbers like that :

[image]

And I would like to average on each row over the columns, meaning to take the average for the first line (2455.93+930.0.654+...)/7, for the second line (1434.56+9443.026+...)/8 . I know how to do it line by line but I don't know what would be the formula to do it for all the rows all at once plz.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to enter `=average(A1:A8)` into cell A9, then copy that down for all the rows.

https://www.excelfunctions.net/basic-excel.html

Comment: This suggests the right function, but consider cleaning up the answer to more accurately reflect the question.  Also, it's not obvious where to find supplemental info at your link.  It might be more useful to use one like https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-average-function.